# Make geom's bigger based on density in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently mapping out values as Geoms on `ggplot`. These values are on the y axis and their categories are on the x axis.

Data looks something like this:

```
Value   condition
1         TRUE
1         TRUE
1         TRUE
6         TRUE
10        TRUE
```

Minimal running example:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,1,6), TRUE) 
colnames(df) <- c("value", "condition")
ggplot(df, aes(x = condition, y = value)) + geom_point()
```

So for instance, at value `1` under condition `TRUE`, how could I make the dot (or whatever shape) *larger* than the others, as it has a larger number of data points there.

6 ones has more data points than 3 threes or 1 two or 1 six.
So one would be the biggest in this example, 3 would be next, while 2 and 6 would be the same size

Comment: I think you want to add `size = value` in `aes()`. If I am reading your question right, you probably want `size = -value` in `aes()`

Comment: The problem is that I don't want it to correspond with the VALUE just the COUNT of the value

Comment: I see. You may want to revise your question including the counting part.

Comment: I made some small change, but I'm not sure how it's not clear on that point. For example, why would I want the 1 dot to be larger than the 10? Only because there are 6 seperate datapoints there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `dplyr` package, you can reshape your data. Then, you can draw a figure.

```
mydf <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,1,6), TRUE) 
colnames(mydf) <- c("value", "condition")

library(dplyr)
count(mydf, condition, value) -> mydf2 

ggplot(mydf2, aes(x = condition, y = value, size = n)) + geom_point()
```

[image]